# Swift lazy variable and didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, lazy-initialization

I want to load a nib file lazily, in Swift, so I do

```
lazy var MyNib: UINib?  = {
    let uiNib:UINib = MyClass.nib();
    return uiNib;
    }()
```

I understand this is only ever called once.

So, if I get a didReceiveMemoryWarning, tests seem to show that setting it to nil has no effect in that it is not re-initialized when accessed at a later date, as can be done with Objective C properties.

More of an issue is NSFetchedResultControllers in that I may genuinely may wish to unload a load of data and then reload at a later date.

How can this be achieved in Swift?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use a backing private property which is initially `nil`, and implement a computed property around it. The computed property implements both getter and setter, with the getter checking whether the baking property is nil, initializing it if needed.

```
private var _nib: UINib?

var uiNib: UINib {
    get {
        if _nib == nil {
            _nib = MyTestClass.nib();
        }
        return _nib!
    }
    set { _nib = nil }
}
```

This way you can set the property to `nil` as many times as you want, being sure that the next time it is accessed in read mode it is reinitialized again.

Note that this implementation is not thread safe - but most likely it will be used from the main thread only.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. This strikes me as a more powerful feature than just using 'lazy'.  So I wonder why lazy should even be bothered with????

Comment: The use case of the lazy is just when the property is initialized once and share its lifetime with the class instance lifetime. It's useful in several cases, just not yours :)

Comment: I agree with @Fittoburst a lazy when 'nil' would be a nice addition.